# Storing 13 Million floats and integer in redis

Tags: redis

[image]I have a file with 13 million floats each of them have a associated index as integer. The original size of file is 80MB.

We want to pass multiple indexes to get float data. The only reason, I needed hashmap field and value as List does not support passing multiple indexes to get.

Stored them as hashmap in redis, with index being field and float as value. On checking memory usage it was about 970MB.

Storing 13 million as list is using 280MB.

Is there any optimization I can use.

Thanks in advance

running on elastic cache

Answer (score 3):

You can do a real good optimization by creating buckets of index vs float values.
Hashes are very memory optimized internally.
So assume your data in original file looks like this:

```
index, float_value

2,3.44
5,6.55
6,7.33
8,34.55
```

And you have currently stored them one index to one float value in hash or a list.
You can do this optimization of bucketing the values:

Hash key would be index%1000, sub-key would be index, and value would be float value.

More details [here](https://instagram-engineering.com/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs-in-redis-1091ae80f74c) as well :

> At first, we decided to use Redis in the simplest way possible: for
>   each ID, the key would be the media ID, and the value would be the
>   user ID:
>
> SET media:1155315 939 GET media:1155315
>
> > 939 While prototyping this solution, however, we found that Redis needed about 70 MB to store 1,000,000 keys this way. Extrapolating to
> >     the 300,000,000 we would eventually need, it was looking to be around
> >     21GB worth of data — already bigger than the 17GB instance type on
> >     Amazon EC2.
>
> We asked the always-helpful Pieter Noordhuis, one of Redis’ core
>   developers, for input, and he suggested we use Redis hashes. Hashes in
>   Redis are dictionaries that are can be encoded in memory very
>   efficiently; the Redis setting ‘hash-zipmap-max-entries’ configures
>   the maximum number of entries a hash can have while still being
>   encoded efficiently. We found this setting was best around 1000; any
>   higher and the HSET commands would cause noticeable CPU activity. For
>   more details, you can check out the zipmap source file.
>
> To take advantage of the hash type, we bucket all our Media IDs into
>   buckets of 1000 (we just take the ID, divide by 1000 and discard the
>   remainder). That determines which key we fall into; next, within the
>   hash that lives at that key, the Media ID is the lookup key *within*
>   the hash, and the user ID is the value. An example, given a Media ID
>   of 1155315, which means it falls into bucket 1155 (1155315 / 1000 =
>   1155):
>
> HSET "mediabucket:1155" "1155315" "939" HGET "mediabucket:1155"
>   "1155315"
>
> > "939" The size difference was pretty striking; with our 1,000,000 key prototype (encoded into 1,000 hashes of 1,000 sub-keys each),
> >     Redis only needs 16MB to store the information. Expanding to 300
> >     million keys, the total is just under 5GB — which in fact, even fits
> >     in the much cheaper m1.large instance type on Amazon, about 1/3 of the
> >     cost of the larger instance we would have needed otherwise. Best of
> >     all, lookups in hashes are still O(1), making them very quick.
>
> If you’re interested in trying these combinations out, the script we
>   used to run these tests is available as a Gist on GitHub (we also
>   included Memcached in the script, for comparison — it took about 52MB
>   for the million keys)

Comment: Thanks, are you suggesting we break 100,00,00 key value pair into 1000 hash keys with each having 1000 key value pair                                                                                                             HAShKey-0-999 will hold key value pair of 0 - 999                                                                                         HAShKey-1000-1999 will hold key value pair of 1000 - 1999

Comment: yes. create for 1 million key value pairs, create 1000 hashes each having 1000 subkey-values. You can play with bucket size i.e. 1000 or 500 or 2500 to come to an optimal overall size, but I guess 1000 shall suffice. It is also good to know about the ‘hash-max-ziplist-entries’ configuration of Redis to tune this more.

Comment: Thanks, set hash-max-zipmap-entries to 1000 and now creating batches of 500, has reduced the size by 5 times. I will continue playing. Keep you posted.

Comment: Great to hear this, share further results too !

Comment: Thanks, moved on to testing gets. settled on for a bucket size of 400. which reduced memory footprint from 980MB to 358MB. Still  too large. Bucket size of 400 created 34300 different hashkeys. Getting all 13 Million index now takes 22 seconds. while without bucket partition, I was getting 4-5 seconds. Looks like I have to compromise with either storage or read. Not both.